# How to get desired value from autocomplete jquery function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, autocomplete

My Jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Origin(sender, args) {

    $(function () {
        $("#<%=txtInfo.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/Get") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    mustMatch: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {

                    }
                });
            },

            select: function (e, i) {

                $("#<%=hdnInfo.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);

                info1()                     

            },                    
            minLength: 0
        }).bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); });              

        });
   }       

</script>
```

The  return {label: item.split('-')[0],val: item.split('-')[1] } shows that value after split from '-' for example:If the value is "abc-2223" then it returns "abc"
But if the value is "A-1 abc-2223" then it returns only "A" but i want "A-1 abc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apply this logic.**    [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PMjnG/)

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var items = ["abc-2223", "A-1 abc-2223"];
        $.each(items, function (key, value) {
            var item = value;

            var text = "";
            var chkItem = item.split('-')[0];
            if (chkItem.length == 1) {
                text = item.substring(item.lastIndexOf("-") + 0, item.length);
                text = item.replace(text, "");
            }
            else {
                text = chkItem;
            }
            alert(text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Update**

As you requested to change your code; please change `success` function like below code.

```
success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {

            //Filter item on condition
            var txtLabel = "";
            var chkItem = item.split('-')[0];
            if (chkItem.length == 1) {
                txtLabel = item.substring(item.lastIndexOf("-") + 0, item.length);
                txtLabel = item.replace(txtLabel, "");
            }
            else {
                txtLabel = chkItem;
            }

            return {
                label: txtLabel,
                val: item.split('-')[1] //you have not specified for value field.
            }
        }))
    },
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply can you please modify my function accordingly?

Comment: I am new to jquery can you please modify my jquery function to do the same.@Ashwini Verma

Comment: Please see my update. If your existing "val: item.split('-')[1]" is correct then that's fine, otherwise change it accordingly or tell me what there should be with example so that I can change that too.

Comment: that code is still working for these new value too. check this sample  http://jsfiddle.net/FBVH6/. May be you doing something wrong while merging the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your server sends in its response an array of strings (`data.d`).

Have your server directly return an array of `{"label":"...","val":"..."}` objects instead.